# How to reuse the same functionality in useEffect and another action inside component?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I want to reuse the function resolveSessionData() inside a component. It is used to set some state on a prop change as well as in a user action. Is this the correct way to reuse the functionality or is there any better way in React?

```
const { useEffect, useState } = require("react");

const Component = ({someProp}) => {
  const [itemData, setItemData] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (someProp) {
        resolveSessionData();
    }
  }, [someProp]);

  const resolveSessionData = () => {
    const data = database.getItemData();
    setItemData(data);
  };

  return <div>
    {/* show item data */}
    <button onClick={resolveSessionData}>
        Activate Lasers
    </button>
  </div>;
};
```

Comment: when you do ```onClick={resolveSessionData()}``` you are calling the function, in the onClick just put the function definition and then when the button is clicked it will then call the function for you like this ```<button onClick={resolveSessionData}>```

Comment: Sorry. It was a typo

Answer (score 4):

To **reuse the functionality of useEffect and other functions**, here you **may use custom hook and cover the common functionality** in the custom hook **and re-use in component where you need**.

ex.

```
import React, { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from "react";

// ----------------------------------  Custom Hook  -----------------------------

const useCustomFetch = ({someProp}) => {
    const [itemData, setItemData] = useState(null);

    const resolveSessionData = useCallback(() => {
        const data = database.getItemData(); // fetching data
        setItemData(data); // setting fetched data to state
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (someProp) {
            resolveSessionData(); // or may be fetch data based on props
        }
    }, [someProp]);

    const addNewItem = useCallback(function (dataToAdd) {
        /**
         * write code to add new item to state
        */
    }, [])

    const removeExistingItem = useCallback(function (dataOrIndexToRemove) {
        /**
         * write code to remove existing item from state
        */
    }, [])

    return {
        itemData,
        addNewItem,
        removeExistingItem,
    }
}

// ----------------------------------  Component managing users  -----------------------------

const ComponentUser = ({someProp}) => {
  const {
    addNewItem,
    itemData,
    removeExistingItem
  } = useCustomFetch('users')

  const handleAction = useCallback(function (action, data) {
    if (action === 'add') {
        addNewItem(data) // ex. adding user
    } else if (action === 'remove') {
        removeExistingItem(data) // ex. removing user
    }
  }, [])

  return <div>
    {itemData.map(function () {
        /**
         * render items here // ex. listing users
         */
    })}
    <button onClick={handleAction}>
        Add / Remove
    </button>
  </div>;
};

// ----------------------------------  Component managing posts  -----------------------------

const ComponentPosts = ({someProp}) => {
    const {
      addNewItem,
      itemData,
      removeExistingItem
    } = useCustomFetch('posts') // re-using custom hook
  
    const handleAction = useCallback(function (action, data) {
      if (action === 'add') {
          addNewItem(data) // ex. add new post
      } else if (action === 'remove') {
          removeExistingItem(data) // ex. remove existing post
      }
    }, [])
  
    return <div>
      {itemData.map(function () {
          /**
           * render items here // ex. render posts
           */
      })}
      <button onClick={handleAction}>
          Activate Lasers
      </button>
    </div>;
};
```

Comment: I didn't test the code, but this is the most correct answer here on its face.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is correct way. There is no better way in React.

Comment: That's not true - this could be made into a custom hook.

Answer (score 1):

You'r doing right , but if you introduce any state value into `resolveSessionData` go with `useCallback` version (commented code)

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from "react";

export default function App({ someProp }) {
  const [itemData, setItemData] = useState(null);

//   const resolveSessionData = useCallback((e) => {
//     e.preventDefault();
//    const data = database.getItemData();
//    setItemData(data);
//  },[])
  useEffect(() => {
    if (someProp) {
      resolveSessionData();
    }
  }, [someProp]);

  const resolveSessionData = (e) => {
     e.preventDefault();
    const data = database.getItemData();
    setItemData(data);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {/* show item data */}
      <button onClick={resolveSessionData}>Activate Lasers</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: This will result in a warning to add the resolveSessionData to the dependency array.

Comment: No problem , Add it to deps array of ```useEffect``` if you want use ```useCallback``` version(commented code)

Comment: If `database` is an external dependency (not internal state or property), `useCallback` hook will make `resolveSessionData` constant during the component life-cycle, so it's OK to add it to `useEffect` dependencies array.

Answer (score 1):

from my viewpoint, the props should be used in the constructor useEffect :

```
const { useEffect, useState } = require("react");

const Component = ({someProp}) => {
  const [itemData, setItemData] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => { // constructor
    if (someProp) {
        resolveSessionData();
    },[]);  // <= []
  

  const resolveSessionData = () => {
    const data = database.getItemData();
    setItemData(data);
  };

  return <div>
    {/* show item data */}
    <button onClick={resolveSessionData}>
        Activate Lasers
    </button>
  </div>;
};
```